# Internet Explorer 11 showing up as tablet on desktop

Tags: internet-explorer-11

I need the latest version IE (it was like 11.0.66.11 but I needed 11.0.77.00) but IE kept telling I had the latest. I uninstalled it and installed it again through windows features and now this is what I see, Internet Explorer as if I was on a tablet. There's no developer tools, nothing!

How do I get Desktop Internet Explorer back?

[image]

Comment: OK, can somebody search on google for "IE showing up as tablet on desktop" and find that duplicate? Did it and it didn't show up (search for almost an hour and I am not that dumb). Another case of duplicate syndrome.

Comment: I had trouble.  I [looked](http://superuser.com/search?q=switch+metro+ie+to+desktop+ie) for 3 minutes before I found it.  Still does not change the fact it is a duplicate.  As for finding it on Google, I had no trouble finding hundreds of articles on the subject, so lets not go there.

Comment: If you find using the terms I used (because I didn't) and you want to delete the question, not yourself out. To me this is not a duplicate and I think it can be useful for other users doing the same search I did. That's why I will be leaving it regardless of more intelligent people using this site.

Comment: Once the question is closed as a duplicate it will eventually just be purged.    I am not sure how the question I found isn't a duplicate if it is asking the same question.  I personally cannot delete questions, and even if I did have that ability, I wouldn't delete a duplicate question myself when community will decide and let the system it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It wasn't so difficult after all! Click the tool button and then select "View in the desktop" option.

[image]